# Jquery Mobile pageLoading() Method how does it work?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery Mobile and attempting to learn it as I redevelop this mobile site. So I am doing all my navigation with different divs with data-role="page". and navigating with the #pagename. My question being doing my navigation this way how do I use the loading message and wait to make the transition until the next page is loaded? I tried putting the $.mobile.pageLoading() in the onClick attribute of the link but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using JQM 1.0 beta 1

```
//show
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

//hide
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

**Update:**

This method is also the accepted way to do it in the official 1.0 release.

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/api/methods.html

*mobile.showPageLoadingMsg ()*

Show the page loading message, which is configurable via $.mobile.loadingMessage.
Example:

```
//cue the page loader 
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

*$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg ()*

Hide the page loading message, which is configurable via $.mobile.loadingMessage.
Example:

```
//cue the page loader           
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here (at the bottom) http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html but yeah it's a little vague on examples.

This might help you out: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1397

Comment: Being new to AJAX and JQuery the lack of quality examples in their documentation leaves me confused from time to time sadly.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery mobile 1.4.5 the only thing that helped me is:
$('.ui-loader').hide();