# jQuery Mobile - pageLoading nor progress msg work

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hello kind people of the internet,
There are several other postings related to this, but alas, none have yet resolved my bug...and I can't seem to noodle through just what I'm must be doing wrong.

Here's my test web page (which is a simple mortgage calculator test app):

[http://www.simdock.com/TestJQueryMobile-loadmsg-progress.htm]

I'd like to show a page loading msg, or a progress msg, what ever, as the next page is being rendered when going to page one or page two (or whatever page)...as I'm outputting a long payment schedule list, or whatever list...it takes a bit to generate...so need a page loading and/or progress msg that actually works.

As you transition from the main-menu calculator page, to page one or page two, there should be some sort of a page loading msg come up, but alas, all I can get to work is the alert msg to fire from the event.

I've tried a couple of ways to get a page load msg:

First way was suggested in the following stackoverflow link:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085679/jquery-mobile-pageloading-method-how-does-it-work][1]

The script snippet that pulls up my page one is as follows (which I attempted to emulate from the other postings on this subject):

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#one').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
//PAGE ID "one" SELECTED EVENT
alert('Just selected page one!');
$.mobile.pageLoading(); 
$.mobile.loadingMessage = "calculating payment schedule...";
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
calcMonthlySchedule();
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
</script>
```

---

The above simply doesn't work however...the alert fires, but nothing else happens, and there are no error msgs, etc...

The other way I've tried was from Jonathan Starks book, Building Android Apps with HTML, CCS and JavaScript (nice book!...but a bit pricey).

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#two').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
  //PAGE ID "two" SELECTED EVENT
  alert('Just selected page two!');
  $('body').append('<div id="progress">Loading...</div>');
  calcLongList();
  $('#progress').remove();
  });
 </script>
```

---

The above also doesn't seem to do anything (except fire the alert msg), as no div section is popped up (like it is in the book sample).

Sooooo...in any event, I must not be thinking/doing something or other...but not sure what...any help would sure be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I use `$.mobile.pageLoading();` to show the loading graphics and `$.mobile.pageLoading(true);` to stop it.

For messages, there's the [$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/methods.html) method.

I've created a sample to prove it works. Just for you, Woody: http://jsfiddle.net/a6337/

This method doesn't work on `pagecreate` event, but works on `pageshow`:

```
$('#mypageone').live('pageshow',function(event){
  $.mobile.loadingMessage = "calculating payment schedule..."; 
  $.mobile.pageLoading(); 
  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
  calcLongList();
  //$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/7fxQf/21/

Comment: Hi Tsar ...hmmm...that's the issue: I'm using the same syntax command as you are, but it simply does not work on my page :-(

Comment: Well...here's my hack at a jsfiddle, that demonstrates how the showPageLoadingMsg does not work   http://jsfiddle.net/woody2shoes/7fxQf/5/

Comment: Here's another slightly edited version:      http://jsfiddle.net/woody2shoes/7fxQf/12/

Comment: see my edit. i've commented out `hidePageLoadingMsg` to demonstrate it works, it stops too soon otherwise.

Comment: I'll look/test/hack at your code in the next couple of days...been pretty hectic with other fires...I work on jQuery Mobile when the boss isn't looking (I have multiple bosses...one here, one at home ;-)